# Doctrine/ZF z2d2 tutorial issue

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I'm sure that I'm missing something, but I've spent all day and I still can't get this skeleton doctrine integration project by Jason Gilmour to work:

[github link](https://github.com/wjgilmore/z2d2)

It's quite a simple project, but (after configuring in application.ini)  I run into difficulty trying to generate the schema:

./scripts/doctrine orm:schema-tool:create

GIVES

PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Entities\Account in /var/www/z2d2/application/models/Entities/Account.php on line 12

I think it has something to do with namespaces.

I am using php 5.3.6.

Thanks,

Demian.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't answer your particular question but integration with the Bisna glue http://www.zendcasts.com/unit-testing-doctrine-2-entities/2011/02/ is _really_ easy and might work on the fly for you.

Comment: The "cannot redeclare class" error means that somewhere prior to seeing line 12 of `/var/www/z2d2/application/models/Entities/Account.php`, PHP has seen a class declaration for `Entities\Account`. Search your code for `class Account` and see if any others turn up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the source from github [here](https://github.com/wjgilmore/z2d2) and it seems that the author has made a mistake in the file /application/model/entities/Rank.php. This file is just a duplicate of Account.php - hence the error...

Just delete Rank.php and create your own (or even don't)

Apart from this issue, it looks like a great skeleton to implement zend framework with doctrine.

Thanks for the comments those who responded.

D.